# Как передать пустую переменную через роут в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Зарегистрирован роут в web.php

```
 Route::get('/posts/{cat}','IndexController@index');
```

Если в url указать просто '/posts', подразумевая что $cat пустая,  возвращается страница ошибки, что страница не найдена.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так вы создайте доп правило:  Route::get('/posts','IndexController@index');

Comment: Или мануал откройте https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так правильно указать необязательный параметр в роуте.

```
Route::get('/posts/{cat?}','IndexController@index');
```